# Should I use PIR or mineral wool (or both) to insulate an interior-ish brick wall?

Tags: insulation

**TL;DR**: exposed wall of a brick room in a shed-like roofed structure, what to insulate with?

I live in a late 19th century log house in central Russia. It's got an uninsulated extension, as most of those houses did, that served as a sort of a vestibule, storage, attic access, and a wind- and rain-proof shed ([here's a Russian Wikipedia link](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) if anyone fancies an adventure in Google Translate).

The extension had a brick wall built in it that connects to the house and serves as the bathroom. I am now insulating this room. I've already replaced old insulation on its roof with 100 mm mineral wool, and planning on doubling that.

What remains now is a single exposed brick wall. It's shielded against rain and wind, save for an occasional stray drop or a draft, as well as from light. I'm guessing there's at least 100 millimetres of brick there, possibly 150 or even 200, but I have no way of knowing for sure. What should I use for insulation - mineral wool or PIR plates?

Using both would be hard, but I figure a few wall plugs (anchors) would do the trick.

Comment: Is foam-glass an option where you're at? It's non-combustible (like mineral wool) but vapor closed (like rigid foamboards)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I couldn't find any, nor have heard of the material before, though it seems very cool. I've got some fire-proof PIR plates, or at least they claim so, and in the very unlikely event of a fire the foam boards and the brick wall are the least combustible materials there - "perks" of living in a wooden house.

Comment: Yeah, most foamboards are somewhat fire-resistant (more like limited-combustible than non-combustible though)

Comment: AIUI, though, foam may melt instead of burning, but tends to release a lot of toxins. Just something for consideration and _not_ intended to steer you away from foam.